# OpenAL alcOpenDevice hangs

Tags: ubuntu, openal

I am using openAl for audio and I recently encountered an issue where during initialisation my program will hang at the following line: "ALCdevice* device = alcOpenDevice(NULL);" I haven't had much luck in searching for a solution (most people have an issue where it returns NULL).

Are there any reasons why this function would hang, and at the very least, a way I can detect this issue in advance?

I suspect the issue is exposed by my audio driver occasionally crashing (on Ubuntu 13.10). However resolving that crash doesn't really solve the problem (i.e. my program hanging).

Answer (score 0):

Did you install oalinst.exe ?

When I Installed it ,

alcOpenDevice(NULL) not return NULL again

You can try it !